# EmguCV detect keypoints from 3D Model

Tags: surf, emgucv, object-recognition, keypoint

Is there a way i can retrieve the observed keypoints from a 3D model instead from an image. This is since i need to track an uneven object (simple spaceship right now: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC129855.jpg) that can be visible from any side. Currently the system works somewhat fine when using an image but like i said i need it be able to identify the model if being viewed from any side. Currently using an implementation of the SURF tutorial found over here:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp

Moreover is there a way to specify the detail of the keypoints or the number?